# tree command with icons

Tags: icons, tree

We all love the `tree` command, but it would be amazing to have the icons next to the files, as both the file browser of VSC or `Color Ls` have.
Does anyone know any way to implement it?

[image: tree vs ls vs vsc]

Answer (score 4):

This already exists, for example in the shape of the `lsd --tree` "enhanced `ls` alternative". It has a limited range of icons, due to technical reasons:

Basically, icons on the console either need a specifically modified terminal emulator (`kitty`, whose subtle bugs I learned to hate), or a font with the desired icons mapped to some code point.

If the icons you get fulfill your needs, then `lsd --tree` is the way to go. Implementing the same is not that hard; use your favourite scripting language to recursively list your directory, print the file names including the icons (inferred either from the name or `file` / magic), and indent as appropriate for a tree.

Comment: `lsd` is very good. `exa` is another option.

Comment: very good bro, thanks!

Comment: wow, mind blown

Answer (score 2):

**Update:** `exa` is now [unmaintained](https://github.com/ogham/exa). Use the maintained replacement [`eza`](https://eza.rocks/) instead.

You might want to try [`exa`](https://the.exa.website/).

I have this alias to get the tree with icons:

```
alias lt='exa -aT --color=always --group-directories-first --icons' # tree listing
```

**Note:** the “–git-ignore” command line argument to tell exa to skip all the files that match the patterns in the current “.gitignore” file.

**Note:** you need a “Nerd” font to get the icon symbols. This is the one I install in Arch:

```
sudo pacman -S ttf-arimo-nerd
```

More examples in this blog post: https://www.lorenzobettini.it/2023/02/exa-and-icon-fonts-in-arch-linux/